# User manager methods create() and create_user()

Tags: django, django-users, django-managers

I have encountered with some suspicious behavior of `create()` method of `User` object manager. Looks like `password` field isn't required for creating `User` object if you use this method. In result you get `User` with blank `password`. In case when you use `create_user` method and don't specify `password` it creates `User` with unusable password (through to `set_unusable_password()`).

I am not sure why `create()` method doesn't `raise exception` when you try to create user without `password` - in documentation it's specified that this field is required.
Is something wrong in `create()` method/documentation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's exactly why the user model has a custom manager with a [`UserManager.create_user()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L149) method for creating users. There are two problems with using the `QuerySet.create()` method on `User` instances:

1. If you run the management command `python manage.py sql`, pay attention to the `auth_user` schema:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE "auth_user" (
       ...
       "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
       ...
   )
   ```

   In SQL, an empty string, `''`, does not equate to `NULL`, i.e. `ISNULL('') != TRUE`.
2. `QuerySet.create()` and `QuerySet.update()` **do not trigger model validation**. Model validation only happens when `ModelForm` instances call the `Model.full_clean()` instance method.

   Raising a validation error in the context of working with the `QuerySet` API directly simply makes no sense in Django. That's why you can do something like `User.objects.create(username='foo', password='')` even though `CharField().validate(value='', None)` would raise a `ValidationError` for a blank string.

For the reasons above, you should defer from using `User.objects.create()` and rely on the supplied `User.objects.create_user()` method from the model's custom manager.

Comment: what if I don't use ModelForm and want to trigger model validation?

Answer (score 1):

Look at django's source User model, there's a custom manager, snippet:

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    # ...   
    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = UserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
                          is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                          last_login=now, date_joined=now)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Comment: I understand that password isn't required for create_user. It has been implemented if you authenticate against some external source. I just thinking that it's not appropriate behavior for User's manager create() method.

Comment: No, because User has a custom manager defined but uses the same variable 'objects' create