# What is the difference between various methods of creating a User object in django?

Tags: python, django, object

I searched, but could not find a proper answer for this. Currently in django we have three ways to create a User with custom manager-

**1)** By creating object instance and calling `save()` on it-

```
u = User(name="some_name", password="some_password")
u.save()
```

**2)** By calling `create()` on manager-

```
u = User.objects.create(name="some_name", password="some_password")
```

**3)** By calling `create_user()` on manager-

```
u = User.objects.create_user(name="some_name", password="some_password")
```

Information such as how each of them works internally and how they are similar and different, will be really helpful.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544398/user-manager-methods-create-and-create-user).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods 1) and 2) are generic methods to create a model instance. They do not do anything specific to the `User` model.

This means that the value you set as a password is not hashed, but is saved as-is. Django won't recognize is as a properly salted and hashed password, and you won't  be able to login.

To properly set a password, use `User.set_password()`:

```
u = User(name="some_name")
u.set_password("some_password")
u.save()
```

Note that you can't do the same with method 2) without an additional database query.

Method 3) is a convenience function that handles all the specifics of the `User` model, like hashing the password.

Answer (score 2):

1) and 2) are identical in terms of what they do. The difference is that with method 1 you explicitly choose when to commit the object to the database with `save`.

Regarding 3, this is from the docs:

> create_user(username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields)
>
> Creates, saves and returns a User.
>
> The username and password are set as given. The domain portion of
>   email is automatically converted to lowercase, and the returned User
>   object will have is_active set to True.
>
> If no password is provided, set_unusable_password() will be called.
>
> The extra_fields keyword arguments are passed through to the User’s
>   **init** method to allow setting arbitrary fields on a custom User model.

So `create_user` looks like it applies a lowercase filter to the email, and sets an unusable password (preventing the user from being able to log in).

Comment: An unusable password and a random password are not the same. An unusable password is saved as a specific token that disallows any login whatsoever.