# Only allow users to register usernames starting with @ in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Hey guys when registering users I only want them to be able to use names starting with @ I have been looking in documentation for Django all day but don't seem to be able to find where I could edit this. Any help would be awesome thank you!

Comment: If all usernames start with an `@` you don't need to store it.

Comment: Take a look at the models on Speedy Net [https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/master/speedy/core/accounts/models.py] and see how fields are validated (search for "validators"). But, is "@" part of the username? Because you can just save the username after the "@" without saving the "@" character to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write [a custom user manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example). And overwrite `create_user` and `create_superuser` methods according to your needs. Then use these methods for creating users.

Also you might want to read [User manager methods create() and create_user()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544398/user-manager-methods-create-and-create-user).